# Installing Caliburn.Micro NuGet Package always fails

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, caliburn.micro

I am attempting to compile the Caliburn.Micro projects from [GitHub](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro) so I can generate the DLL's to use in my own project - a Caliburn.Micro Xamarin Native Android project.

I have loaded the Caliburn.Micro.sln (located in the `src` folder) into Visual Studio 2012 professional and attempted to build the `Caliburn.Micro` project. I get 40 errors relating to metadata. For example;

```
Error   5   Metadata file '_Tests\Caliburn.Micro-xamarin\Caliburn.Micro-xamarin\bin\net45\Debug\Caliburn.Micro.Platform.dll' could not be found _Tests\Caliburn.Micro-xamarin\Caliburn.Micro-xamarin\src\Caliburn.Micro.Tests.NET45\CSC Caliburn.Micro.Tests.NET45
```

So I have attempted to install the `Caliburn.Micro` NuGet package on this project and I get the following errors. I have also created my own new solution and attempted to install the `Caliburn.Micro` NuGet package and the same error occurs.

Any ideas what is going wrong?

```
PM> Install-Package Caliburn.Micro
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Caliburn.Micro.Core (= 2.0.2)'.
Installing 'Caliburn.Micro.Core 2.0.2'.
Successfully installed 'Caliburn.Micro.Core 2.0.2'.
Installing 'Caliburn.Micro 2.0.2'.
Successfully installed 'Caliburn.Micro 2.0.2'.
Adding 'Caliburn.Micro.Core 2.0.2' to Caliburn.Micro.
Uninstalling 'Caliburn.Micro.Core 2.0.2'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Caliburn.Micro.Core 2.0.2'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: supportedFrameworks
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Caliburn.Micro
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

The ArgumentOutOfRangeException with the argument name being supportedFrameworks usually means there is something wrong with one or more of your Portable Class Library (PCL) profiles.

NuGet looks at the .xml files in various PCL directories, for example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile259\SupportedFrameworks
```

If for some reason NuGet does not find any non-Xamarin profile xml files in one of these directories it will throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. The SupportedFrameworks directory will either be empty or may just have Xamarin .xml files in there, both of these problems will cause the ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

To find which PCL profile has missing .xml files you can either look at every PCL profile directory or debug NuGet.

I usually use a [console app](https://github.com/mrward/mono-portable-class-library-util) that uses NuGet but you can easily debug, passing it the **list** command line argument which will trigger the same code path as NuGet version 2. If you then put a breakpoint on the [line of code that throws the ArgumentOutOfRangeException](https://github.com/mrward/mono-portable-class-library-util/blob/28d8eb80fdbb4843a38e1703b3fc5b341f52b1db/src/NetPortableProfile.cs#L62) you should be able to see which PCL profile is causing a problem.